# Playframework 1.x Unauthorized response with Negotiate header

Tags: playframework, http-headers, playframework-1.x

How could I return in Playframework 1.x Unauthorized response with Negotiate header?

This doesn't work:

```
response.status = Http.StatusCode.UNAUTHORIZED;
response.setHeader("WWW-Authenticate", "Negotiate");
render();
```

Comment: There is unauthorized() method but it rewrites response with response.setHeader("WWW-Authenticate", "Basic realm=\"" + realm + "\"");

Comment: Your code should work. If I copy and paste the above into a brand new project (Play 1.3.0), I get the [expected results](http://i.imgur.com/vaTuCCF.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
response.status = Http.StatusCode.UNAUTHORIZED;
response.setHeader("WWW-Authenticate","DEMOHEADER");
renderText("Hello PLay");//renderHtml("<p>Hello Play</p>")
```